# Show icons for Navigation with toggle-mode "slide over content"

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I want to achieve is a navigation menu with icons always visible, and after clicking the sidebar-toggle, the menu should slide over the content and show the navigation icons.

What I want to achieve is a navigation menu with icons always visible, and after clicking the sidebar-toggle, the menu should slide over the content and show the navigation icons.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

#toggle_icon {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  margin:6px;
}
.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="sidebar">
  <a href="#" style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between; margin:0px 5px;"><i class="fa fa-stethoscope"></i><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
  <a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a>
  <a href="#services"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-wrench"></i> Services</a>
  <a href="#clients"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h2>Sidebar with Icons</h2>
  <p>ntur his ad. Eum no moles.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum .</p>
  <p>efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What technologies are you using? You might get better answers if you post some more information and add additional tags.

Comment: Dear sir i have added the question again when it is collapsed after click then i also want to hide the stethoscope icon

Comment: Please ask an actual question. Are you expecting to use CSS only or JS too? I've improved the tags of your question, but please make them show exactly what your question is *about*

Comment: yes add javascript too

Comment: now it is clear to understand

Answer (score 0):

Here, I've done it for you. Take a look if it's helping you to overcome your problems.
I've user latest build of `jquery`

```js
function ToggleSidebar(e) {
    var sidebar_width = parseInt($('.sidebar').css('width').trim().split('px')[0]);
    if(sidebar_width > 60){
        $(".sidebar").css('width', '60px');
        $(".sidebar-control").fadeOut();
        $(".nav-left-icon").fadeOut();
    }
    else {
        $(".sidebar").css('width', '160px');                
        $(".sidebar-control").fadeIn();
        $(".nav-left-icon").fadeIn();
    }
};
```

```css
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

#toggle_icon {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  margin:6px;
}
.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 16px;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar-control{
    position: absolute;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="nav-switcher">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="ToggleSidebar(event)" style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between; margin:0px 5px;">
            <i class="fa fa-stethoscope nav-left-icon"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
  </div>
  <a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i><span class="sidebar-control">&nbsp;Home</span></a>
  <a href="#services"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-wrench"></i><span class="sidebar-control">&nbsp;Services</span></a>
  <a href="#clients"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i><span class="sidebar-control">&nbsp;Clients</span></a>
  <a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i><span class="sidebar-control">&nbsp;Contacts</span></a>
</div>

  <div class="main">
    <h2>Sidebar with Icons</h2>
    <p>ntur his ad. Eum no moles.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum .</p>
    <p>efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you sir a lot and it's working properly now. thank you good luck